# flexbox size not the same for all items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the fiddle below the first 2 items display next to each other in a row, but as there's only 3 items the 3rd displays with 100%.

I would like this to keep the same width as the other 2 items leaving a blank space where there is no item.

I have also set the width of these items to 40% and it is displays as 50% each with a 10px margin which is fine but I was under the impression you needed flex: 1 auto; to set the width in this way. however doing that would mean all boxes would display with 100% when pulling from a DB.

https://jsfiddle.net/ffr9rhrw/

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
    <div class="rev-col">
<div class="reviews-main-wrap">
            <div class="reviews-main-img"><img class="u-full-width"     src="../../images/reviews/{{ $review->img }}" ></div>
            <div class="reviews-main-header"><h6>{!! $review->header   !!}</h6></div>   
            <div class="reviews-main-price">Price £££</div> 
            <div class="reviews-main-content">{!!   str_limit($review->content, $limit = 100) !!}</div>
            <div class="reviews-readmore">Read More</div></a>
</div>  
</div>
        <div class="rev-col">
<div class="reviews-main-wrap">
            <div class="reviews-main-img"><img class="u-full-width" src="../../images/reviews/{{ $review->img }}" ></div>
            <div class="reviews-main-header"><h6>{!! $review->header !!}</h6></div> 
            <div class="reviews-main-price">Price £££</div> 
            <div class="reviews-main-content">{!! str_limit($review->content, $limit = 100) !!}</div>
            <div class="reviews-readmore">Read More</div></a>
</div>  
</div>
        <div class="rev-col">
<div class="reviews-main-wrap">
            <div class="reviews-main-img"><img class="u-full-width" src="../../images/reviews/{{ $review->img }}" ></div>
            <div class="reviews-main-header"><h6>{!! $review->header !!}</h6></div> 
            <div class="reviews-main-price">Price £££</div> 
            <div class="reviews-main-content">{!! str_limit($review->content, $limit = 100) !!}</div>
            <div class="reviews-readmore">Read More</div></a>
</div>  
</div>
    </div>

<!-- sidebar content -->
    <div class="sidebar">
    @yield('sidebar')
    </div>  
</div>
```

css

```
.container { display:flex; flex-flow: row wrap; max-width:1200px; margin:0 auto; padding: 0 10px;}
.header { flex: 1 100%; height:50px; background-color:#ff00ff;}
.main {display:flex; flex-flow: row wrap; flex:1; background-color:; }
.sidebar { flex: 0 250px; margin-left:10px;background-color:#ec2350; }
.center {   -webkit-justify-content: center; justify-content: center; } 

.rev-wrap{ display:flex; flex-flow: row wrap; background-color:#ececec;}
.rev-col:first-child{flex:1 40%; margin-left:0px; background-color:#ff00ff;}
.rev-col{flex:1 40%; margin-left:10px; background-color:#ff00ff;}
.rev-column:nth-child(odd){ flex:1 40%; margin-left:0px; background-color:#ff00ff;}
.rev-header{flex:1 auto; height:auto; padding:10px;background-color:#ff0000;} 
.reviewscontainer     { width: 100%; height:auto; margin: 0 auto; background-color:#f9f9f9; color:#2c3e50; }
.reviews-main-wrap{border:0px solid #ccc;height:auto; margin-bottom:2%; ov
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding '.rev-column:nth-child(odd)' not removing margin. That is because your element has a class name 'rev-col'.

This means the CSS should be

```
.rev-col:nth-child(odd){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what exactly you want to do,
First thing i don't think this style [flex:1 250px] is correct, you should use [flex:1 Auto; max-width:250px] other incorrect styles you'r using are [flex:1 40%], the correct way to go is [flex:1] or [flex:1 1 Auto] or [flex:1 1 0]... so on (You get the picture!).
Now, Since the container is [display:felx] then this div container should be filled with it's contained element.
So, one way to go is simply to add another div in order to fill the blank space,
Another way to go is to set the container to [display:inline-flex] this will cause the container div to align to the left and set its size according to its content.

Another way which i think will answer your needs the best is just to set max-width for both left columns and their container, this will prevent them from growing more then expected.

```
.main {display:flex; max-width:600px; flex-flow: row wrap; flex:1; background-color:; }

.rev-col:first-child{flex:1; max-width:300px; margin-left:0px; background-
color:#ff00ff;}

.rev-col{flex:1; max-width:300px; margin-left:10px; background-color:#ff00ff;}

.rev-col:nth-child(odd){ flex:1; max-width:300px; margin-left:0px; background-color:#ff00ff;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wtesnrp7/